Question on orthogonal polynomials
I want to prove the Christoffel-Darboux formula, saying that for any three consecutive orthogonal polynomials $p_i$, we have
$$p_n(x) = (a_n x + b_n) p_{n-1}(x) - c_n p_{n-2}(x)$$
where $a, b, c$ are constants, $a, c >0$ (I drop the indices).
The proof I read states that we take $a$ such that $p_n - axp_{n-1}$ is of degree at most $n-1$ (which is possible since $p_i$ is of degree $i$). This is therefore a linear combination $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i$ where the indices range from $0$ to $n-1$.
Now, they state that $\lambda_i$ has to be zero for $i < n-2$, but I cannot figure out why?

What about this proof in Wikipedia?

Assume without loss of generality that we're working on the interval $(a,b)=(-1,1)$. Given a weight function $w \in C(-1,1)$ such that $w(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$ and $\int_{-1}^1 w(x) \, dx < \infty$, we can define an inner product for $f, g \in C(-1,1)$ as follows:
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 w(x) f(x) g(x) \, dx. $$
A sequence of polynomials is considered orthogonal if $\langle p_k, p_j \rangle = 0$ whenever $k \neq j$. For convenience, these polynomials can be normalized, for example, by requiring them to be monic and orthonormal (edit: This is not possible for any sequence of orthogonal polynomials. We assume it here to make the proof cleaner, though orthogonality is enough with a little change). Such a sequence of polynomials exhibits a three-term recurrence relation. This can be understood as follows:
Fix $n > 1$ and assume that the orthogonal polynomials $\{P_0, \ldots, P_{n-1}\}$ have already been constructed. To construct $P_n$, we can use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. Specifically, consider the monic polynomial of degree $n$, $xP_{n-1}(x)$, and subtract its projection onto $S_n := \text{span} \{P_0, \ldots, P_{n-1}\}$. In general, for any two vectors $v$ and $w$, the projection of $v$ onto $w \neq 0$ is given by:
$$ \text{proj}_w v = \frac{\langle v, w \rangle}{\langle w, w \rangle} w. $$
Since we have chosen $\langle P_k, P_k \rangle = 1$, we obtain a monic polynomial $P_n$ that is orthogonal to $S_n$ through the Gram-Schmidt procedure:
$$ P_n(x) := xP_{n-1}(x) - \text{proj}_{S_n} (xP_{n-1}(x)) $$
$$ = xP_{n-1}(x) - \langle xP_{n-1}, P_{n-1} \rangle P_{n-1} - \langle xP_{n-1}, P_{n-2} \rangle P_{n-2} - \ldots - \langle xP_{n-1}, P_0 \rangle P_0. $$
However, by definition, $P_{n-1}$ is orthogonal to $S_{n-1} = \mathcal{P}_{n-2}$, the space of polynomials with degree $\leq n-2$. In particular, $P_{n-1}$ is orthogonal to $xP_k$ for $k < n-2$ (since the degree is $\leq n-2$). Thus, by the definition of the inner product,
$$ \langle xP_{n-1}, P_k \rangle = \langle P_{n-1}, xP_k \rangle = 0 $$
for all $k < n-2$, as desired.

You cannot require the polynomials to be both monic and orthonormal. Consider, for instance, the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$, for which $w(x)=1$. $P_0(x)=1$ and $P_1(x)=x$ are monic, but $\int_{-1}^1P_0^2(x),dx=2$ and $\int_{-1}^1P_1^2(x),dx=\frac{2}{3}.$

Sure, but the orthogonality is sufficient here, so the above holds for the more general case. Similar proof holds and shows $(n + 1) P_{n+1}(x) = (2n + 1) x P_n(x) - n P_{n-1}(x)$ for Legendre polynomials, for example. Thank you I'll add an edit.
